# RuntimeException in Java code

Tags: java

This code compiles and I can get results, when I run it on Netbeans, but I always get a RuntimeException.
I found out on [Javadocs](http://javadocs.com/docs/com.facebook.jcommon/concurrency/0.1.9/com/facebook/concurrency/RuntimeExceptionHandler.java), that this is the superclass of those exceptions that can be thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine. How can I get rid of it?

```
// i++
float Etplus, TrueEplus, TrueVplus, fplus1=0;
//  Summation from i=1 to 10000
for (int i=1;i<=10000;i++){
    fplus1 +=(float) 1/(Math.pow(i,4));
}
TrueVplus = (float) ((Math.pow(Math.PI, 4)) / 90);
TrueEplus = (float) TrueVplus - fplus1;
Etplus = (float)(TrueEplus/TrueVplus)*100;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Ft(i++) = "+TrueVplus + "\n\nFa(i++) = " +fplus1 + "\n\nEt(i++) = ("+Etplus+ ")%","Results for i++ (Float)", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

// i--
float Etminus, TrueEminus, TrueVminus, fminus1=0;

//  Summation from i=10000 to 1
for (int j=10000;j>=1;j--){
    fminus1 += (double) 1/(Math.pow(j, 4));
}

TrueVminus = (double) (Math.pow((Math.PI), 4))/90;
TrueEminus = (double) TrueVminus - fminus1;
Etminus = (double) (TrueEminus/TrueVminus)*100;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Ft(i--) = "
+TrueVminus + "\n\nFa(i--) = " +fminus1 + "\n\nEt(i--) = (" +Etminus+")%","Results for i--(Float)", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: can you share error output. probably it tells line of error

Comment: Can you show us the full method and stacktrace?

Comment: Tell us the complete error (incl. stack trace). Or do you want us to guess?

Comment: if it is an ArithmeticException that's mean that you divide by 0

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are compiling this, because for me, it doesn't. These lines are problematic:

```
TrueVminus = (double) (Math.pow((Math.PI), 4))/90;
TrueEminus = (double) TrueVminus - fminus1;
Etminus = (double) (TrueEminus/TrueVminus)*100;
```

You convert the results to doubles, but the variables themselves are floats. If you do it like this:

```
TrueVminus = (float) (Math.pow((Math.PI), 4))/90;
TrueEminus = (float) TrueVminus - fminus1;
Etminus = (float) (TrueEminus/TrueVminus)*100;
```

then it works for me

Comment: To get rid of [RuntimeException](http://javadocs.com/docs/oracle/j2sdk/1.4.0_04/java/lang/RuntimeException.java) error... You mean change the "float" in `float Etminus, TrueEminus, TrueVminus, fminus1=0;` to double?

Comment: No, change the (double) to (float) in the assignments

Comment: But really, post a stacktrace in your question :(

Comment: Here dave:**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.[RuntimeException](http://javadocs.com/docs/oracle/j2sdk/1.4.0_04/java/lang/RuntimeException.java): Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float at infiniteSeries.main**

Comment: @nickbschwartz that's not exactly what I was hoping for, but ok. My answer should work for you. If it does, please accept it. If it doesn't tell us why

Comment: Just got rid of [RuntimeException](http://javadocs.com/docs/oracle/j2sdk/1.4.0_04/java/lang/RuntimeException.java) dave. TNX